# Vim command line color setting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to set different colors for the command line color and the "Normal" text color in vim.  When I use

```
:hi Normal guifg=orange
```

the command line and the normal text color become orange.  I would like the command line at the bottom of the gui to be a different color however.

Comment: I guess this line is called the cmdline. So its statusline and below it is cmdline. Correct me if im wrong. And I was trying to post this as a feature request on www.vim.org. No such option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not that I know of.

Not without messing with Vim's source.

The command line *is under* Normal highlighting group.

Answer (score 9):

Nowadays NeoVim has the feature. `MsgArea` color group. e.g.

```
:hi MsgArea guifg=#03ff13
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this works in neovim!!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with autocommands:

```
hi Normal=white guifg=white
au CmdLineEnter * hi Normal ctermfg=cyan guifg=cyan
au CmdLineLeave * hi Normal ctermfg=white guifg=white
```

Surprisingly to me, this only affects the CmdLine, not everything else.

I had expected all the normal text to change color immediately when entering the CmdLine. Without the CmdLineLeave, the change to the normal text everywhere happens, but only after getting out of the command line; which explains why it does what we want.

Note that I am using vim from a terminal, so I am using ctermfg instead of guifg; but I anticipate that it will work the same way with a gui version of vim.

You may also want to highlight the ModeMsg.

Answer (score 2):

That can be done via new `wincolor` option that was introduced in Vim 8.2:

```
set wincolor=NormalAlt
autocmd WinEnter set wincolor=NormalAlt
hi Normal       guifg=#CED1CF       guibg=#000000       gui=NONE
hi NormalAlt    guifg=#CED1CF       guibg=#1B1D21       gui=NONE
```

[image]